# Is there any filetype the Google Calendar Android app supports?

Tags: android, calendar

I need to import an .ics-file, which is not supported by the calendar app. So I need a script which converts it into any other filetype google calendar supports. Haven't found any yet...
I know I can import .ics files on desktop, but I need to do it on Android..
.vcs doesn't work either..

Hope you can help me ;)

Comment: Off topics, migrate to Android SE?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are many possible calendar apps on a user's device. None has to be the AOSP Calendar app.

Second, by my reading of [the AOSP Calendar app's manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml), it does not support loading information from local files by way of some `Intent`.

Comment: Such a basic feature, why would google not implement it? Thanks anyway.